# Need the last value of a Gap and Island

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I am a bit stuck right now, I made good headway on this query, but I am not getting the result I expect. I am using BQ Standard SQL. The Table Looks like this.

ID - Unique ID to an account
Stage - where it is in the lifecycle of a customer
CreatedDate - When the stage was updated
EndDate - When the stage ended
Amount - the amount the stage was for

| ID | Stage | CreatedDate | EndDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| egj3k | Discovery | 2020-12-08 | 2020-12-08 | 5000 |
| egj3k | Discovery | 2020-12-08 | 2020-12-10 | 6500 |
| egj3k | Proposal | 2020-12-10 | 2020-12-11 | 6500 |
| egj3k | Proposal | 2020-12-11 | 2020-12-15 | 8000 |
| egj3k | Negotiation | 2020-12-15 | 2020-12-21 | 7500 |
| egj3k | Onboarding | 2020-12-21 | 2020-12-21 | 8000 |
| egj3k | Onboarding | 2020-12-21 | 2020-12-22 | 8000 |
| egj3k | Onboarding | 2020-12-21 | 2020-12-23 | 10000 |
| egj3k | Onboarding | 2020-12-23 | 2020-12-25 | 11000 |
| egj3k | Revenue | 2020-12-25 | 2021-01-31 | 15000 |
| egj3k | Stalled | 2021-01-31 | 2021-02-05 | 7000 |
| egj3k | Revenue | 2021-02-05 | 2021-03-05 | 12000 |

The first problem was finding the Min and Max created date of each Stage so show the life cycle, which I solved this way:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT  ID, 
            Stage, 
            CreatedDate, 
            EndDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreatedDate)
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Stage ORDER BY CreatedDate) As WindowId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Stage ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) As ReverseWindowId
    FROM `BQ_TABLE`
    )
    
    SELECT  DISTINCT ID,
            Stage,
            MIN(CreatedDate) OVER(PARTITION BY WindowId, ReverseWindowId) As StartDate,
            NULLIF(MAX(IFNULL(EndDate, '9999-12-31')) OVER(PARTITION BY WindowId, ReverseWindowId), '9999-12-31') As EndDate
    
    FROM CTE 

    where ID = 'egj3k'
    ORDER BY StartDate
```

Which produces this:

| ID | Stage | CreatedDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| egj3k | Discovery | 2020-12-08 | 2020-12-10 |
| egj3k | Proposal | 2020-12-10 | 2020-12-15 |
| egj3k | Negotiation | 2020-12-15 | 2020-12-21 |
| egj3k | Onboarding | 2020-12-21 | 2020-12-25 |
| egj3k | Revenue | 2020-12-25 | 2021-01-31 |
| egj3k | Stalled | 2021-01-31 | 2021-02-05 |
| egj3k | Revenue | 2021-02-05 | 2021-03-05 |

Perfect. But now I need to find the LAST amount of the window. So I am trying to produce this:

| ID | Stage | CreatedDate | EndDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| egj3k | Discovery | 2020-12-08 | 2020-12-10 | 6500 |
| egj3k | Proposal | 2020-12-10 | 2020-12-15 | 8000 |
| egj3k | Negotiation | 2020-12-15 | 2020-12-21 | 7500 |
| egj3k | Onboarding | 2020-12-21 | 2020-12-25 | 11000 |
| egj3k | Revenue | 2020-12-25 | 2021-01-31 | 15000 |
| egj3k | Stalled | 2021-01-31 | 2021-02-05 | 7000 |
| egj3k | Revenue | 2021-02-05 | 2021-03-05 | 12000 |

I tried doing to Rank the window and select the MAX rank from each. I also tried using LAST_VALUE but it wasn't coming back right. Because you can see there are two classifications for Revenue.

```
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Stage order by CreatedDate Desc) as Rank_

Where Rank_ = 1
```

Help me out? ;) Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try the LAST_VALUE or FIRST_VALUE window function: ```FIRST_VALUE(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY WindowId, ReverseWindowId ORDER BY EndDate DESC) As last_amount```

Comment: You can always handle this by performing the calculation over runs of the same classification, if that's what you had in mind.  Do you have a runnable test case to add to the question?  Do you have expected output?  It's not clear why your result is not what you wanted.

Comment: @JonArmstrong FIRST_VALUE. Great answer, I guess i didn't realize there is that versus LAST and I already created the window with the ID's in the CTE's. That seems to work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array trick to get the last value in each island.  I find your logic to be rather cumbersome.  I'm not sure why you are using `ROW_NUMBER()` four times, why you are checking for a `NULL` value of `CreatedDate`, nor why you are using `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`.

In any case, this should do what you want:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreatedDate) as seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Stage ORDER BY CreatedDate) as seqnum_2
      FROM `BQ_TABLE` t
     )
SELECT ID, Stage, MIN(CreatedDate), MAX(CreatedDate),
       ARRAY_AGG(Amount ORDR BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)]
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID, Stage, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Comment: cumbersome is a good way to describe how I was trying to solve the problem. Didn't know about ARRAY_AGG, or haven't used it much. Appreciate the help and I'll have to read up on that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT  ID, 
            Stage, 
            CreatedDate, 
            EndDate,
            Amount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreatedDate)
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Stage ORDER BY CreatedDate) As WindowId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Stage ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) As ReverseWindowId
    FROM `BQ_Table`
    ),
    CTE_2 as (
    SELECT  ID,
            Stage,
            MIN(CreatedDate) OVER(PARTITION BY WindowId, ReverseWindowId) As StartDate,
            NULLIF(MAX(IFNULL(EndDate, '9999-12-31')) OVER(PARTITION BY WindowId, ReverseWindowId), '9999-12-31') As EndDate,
            Amount,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY  ReverseWindowId, WindowId ORDER BY EndDate desc) as Rev_rank
    
    FROM CTE 


    ORDER BY StartDate)

    SELECT 

    ID,
    Stage,
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    Amount

    FROM CTE_2 

    Where Rev_rank = 1
```

It works, but it's Ugly. Still interested to see if anyone has a better idea

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select id, stage, min(CreatedDate) CreatedDate, max(EndDate) EndDate, 
  array_agg(amount order by EndDate desc limit 1)[offset(0)] amount
from (
  select *, countif(new_stage) over(partition by id order by CreatedDate, EndDate) stage_group
  from (
    select *, 
      ifnull(stage != lag(stage) over(partition by id order by CreatedDate, EndDate), true) new_stage
    from `BQ_Table`    
  )
)
group by id, stage, stage_group
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]